# Typed function parameters using destructuring and rest in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, destructuring, rest-parameters

I have a function:

```
export default ({
  input: { name, onChange, value, ...restInput },
  meta,
  ...rest
}) => (
  ...
);
```

Given that 'name' is a string, 'onChange' is a function, 'value' is a string, 'meta' is an object, how can I add types to those parameters?
My best guess would be like so:

```
export default ({
  input: { (name: String), (onChange: function), (value: String), ...restInput },
  (meta: Object),
  ...rest
}) => (
  ...
);
```

But it seems to have syntax errors. And even more I have no idea how to add types to rest parameters.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To add type declarations to destructured parameters you need to declare the type of the containing *object*.

From the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#function-declarations):

> ... Confusingly, the colon here does not indicate the type. The type, if you specify it, still needs to be written after the entire destructuring...
>
> ```
> let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = o;
> ```

**A PSA about deeply nested destructuring**:

> **Use destructuring with care**. As the previous example demonstrates, *anything but the simplest destructuring expression is confusing*. This is especially true with deeply nested destructuring, which gets really hard to understand even without piling on renaming, default values, and type annotations. **Try to keep destructuring expressions small and simple.** You can always write the assignments that destructuring would generate yourself.

#### Destructuring function parameters

In a function, this is how you would declare types for destructured parameters:

```
export default ({ a, b }: {a: string, b: number}) => (
  ...
);
```

This looks pretty bad on a longer example though:

```
export default ({
  input: { name, onChange, value, ...restInput },
  meta,
  ...rest
}: {
  input: { 
    name: string, onChange: ()=>void, value:string, ...restInput 
  }, meta: object
}) => (
  ...
);
```

Looks pretty bad, so the best you can do here is to declare an interface for your parameters and use that instead of inline types:

```
interface Params {
  input: { 
    name: string;
    onChange: ()=>void;
    value: string;
  }; 
  meta: object;
}

export default ({
  input: { name, onChange, value, ...restInput },
  meta,
  ...rest
}: Params) => {};
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Params%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20input%3A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20()%3D%3Evoid%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20meta%3A%20object%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20input%3A%20%7B%20name%2C%20onChange%2C%20value%2C%20...restInput%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20meta%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...rest%0D%0A%7D%3A%20Params)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B)

[Article with much more](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/13/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript)

### Rest parameters

For the rest parameters, depending on what you expect these types to be, you can use a [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html):

```
interface Params {
  // This needs to match the other declared keys and values
  [key: string]: object;
  input: { 
    [key: string]: string | (() => void);
    name: string;
    onChange: ()=>void;
    value: string;
  }; 
  meta: object;

}

export default ({
    input: { name, onChange, value, ...restInput },
    meta,
    ...rest
}: Params) => { };
```

This will give `...rest` a type of `{[key: string]: object}` for example.

[Rest parameter playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Params%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20input%3A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20()%3D%3Evoid%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20meta%3A%20object%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20input%3A%20%7B%20name%2C%20onChange%2C%20value%2C%20...restInput%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20meta%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...rest%0D%0A%7D%3A%20Params)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B)

Comment: Yes, I think interface is the best option here. But do we normally not type the '...rest'?

Comment: it depends on what you expect in your object. I added an option using index signatures

Comment: How do you add default values for destructured parameters in TypeScript? In plain ES2015 it's easy, `function foo({ param1, param2, optionalParam = 0 })`.