# How to work and define an underlying property of object with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
cellRendererFramework: (params: any) => {
    return (<>{params.data.SOME_PROPERTY_FROM_USER}</>);
},
```

`params` is an object. And I am accessing only params.data all the time.
I would like to define `params.data` with typescript.

This is a working example:

```
cellRendererFramework: (params: any) => {
    const userdata: User = params.data;
    return (<>{userdata.SOME_PROPERTY_FROM_USER}</>);
},
```

Now sonarLint is telling me all the time I should remove the useless declaration of userdata. Understandable, because I am using userdata only to check the data structure of the user is correct.

In my perfect world I would like to write this:

```
cellRendererFramework: (params.data: User) => {
    return (<>{params.data.SOME_PROPERTY_FROM_USER}</>);
},
```

But this is not allowed. Is there any good solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typed function parameters using destructuring and rest in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329592/typed-function-parameters-using-destructuring-and-rest-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object desctructuring assignment with typing added like this:

```js
cellRendererFramework: ({ data }: { data: User }) => {
    return (<>{params.data.SOME_PROPERTY_FROM_USER}</>);
},
```

It is also explained in more detail [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript).