# How do you type in typescript for something like ({html}) parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

VScode complains about html parameter being any, I cannot change to html: string so how to specify a string in this case ?

```
  const concatSource = ({html}) => {
    source = `
      <html>
          ${html}
      </html>
    `
    return souce
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typed function parameters using destructuring and rest in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329592/typed-function-parameters-using-destructuring-and-rest-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
const concatSource = ({
  html
}: { html: string }) => {
  source = `
      <html>
          ${html}
      </html>
    `
  return souce
}
```