# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'string' when migrating my Nodejs code to TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am migrating a Nodejs project to TypeScript. Starting from `index.js`, changed it to `index.ts` and did the necessary change for ts. But now I hit the error

```
src/index.ts:34:90 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'string'.

34   socket.on('login', async function ({ user_id:string}) {...}
```

I have tried most of answers in [Confusing "duplicate identifier" Typescript error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/confusing-duplicate-identifier-typescript-error-message) but they all failed to work for me, which includes:

1. `npm install @types/node --save-dev` and add `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`
2. re-install `node_modules` folder
3. mess with `compilerOptions`

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    // "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"], /* turn it on/off makes no difference */
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true 
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true, /* turn it on/off makes no difference */            
    "skipLibCheck": true   
  },
  "files": ["src/index.ts"], /*I only want to tsc this file*/
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I did not install `@types/express` but according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247, "If a module doesn't have type data available (via a `.d.ts` file), the ES6 module syntax，one must use the CommonJS alternative". It seems to work, so I mix `require` with `import` in my codes.

Could this be the reason ?

```
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
var http = require('http').Server(app)
```

--- update ---

Except for the answer @Jared Smith gave, I find [Typed function parameters using destructuring and rest in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329592/typed-function-parameters-using-destructuring-and-rest-in-typescript) provide more detailed information.

Comment: That syntax doesn't mean what you think it does. You probably want `({user_id}: {user_id:string} )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add type annotations in function parameter destructuring like that. Change your code to this:

```js
socket.on('login', async function ({ user_id }: { user_id:string }) {...}
```

Here in the signature for the callback we have the regular destructuring part `{ user_id }` but the parameter to that function is still an object with a `user_id` property and needs to be typed as such. I'll re-write it below with the type extracted and the parameter non-destructured to maybe help give the idea:

```js
type User = {
  user_id: string
}

socket.on('login', async function (user: User) {
   const user_id = user.user_id;
   // do something
})
```

This is equivalent to the above inlined version and there isn't a syntactic shortcut.

Comment: Say my day! One more question, if I use type User = {...} then I can't do parameter destructuring, right ?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 no you totally can: `async function ({ user_id }: User) {...}` I just spelled it all out to show the correct order of the syntax.