# Desctructure in function props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to run a Flatlist with typescript, but it seems to allow only an expression function that has its props destructured. I cant seem to figure out how desctructure with the necessary type (Suggestion). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Unchanged flatlist function

```
  const renderSuggestions = () => 
         <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onPress={(item:Suggestion) => handleSelect(item)}
        keyExtractor={item => item.place_id}
      />
```

Attempt 1 (error:renderItem overload not found)

```
 const renderItem = (item:Suggestion)=> (

    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity >
        <Text >{item.structured_formatting.main_text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

Attempt 2 (typescript type error (implicit any type))

```
const renderItem = ({item})=> (

    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity >
        <Text >{item.structured_formatting.main_text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

attempt per answer: item / index not found error

```
  const renderItem = (item:Suggestion, index:number)=> (

    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity >
        <Text >{item.structured_formatting.main_text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )


  const renderSuggestions = () => 
         <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item:Suggestion, index:number }) => renderItem(item, index)}
        onPress={(item:Suggestion) => handleSelect(item)}
        keyExtractor={item => item.place_id}
      />
```

Comment: [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640184/1218980) is correct, but about how to type destructured params, here's how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329592/1218980

Comment: Please, ask one question at a time. you have literally changed your whole initial question, which is answered with my answer. The question now reflects something completely different.

Comment: @DavidScholz removed the handleselect stuff to maintain one question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `FlatList` the type of the passed `data` prop determines the type of the destructured `item`. Here is a minimal working example for seeing this.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { FlatList } from "react-native"

type DataType = {
  id: number,
  someThing: string
}
const FlatListWithType = () => {
   // we specify the type here
   const [data, setData] = useState<DataType[]>()

   return (
     <FlatList
       data={data}
       renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

       )}
     />
   )
}
```

The type suggestion should work now.

[image]

Comment: item/ index not found on function call. See my edit, maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: You haven't used the suggestion in my answer. You have typed the destructured elements as well. This is wrong

Comment: You need to type the `data` prop as I have shown. Just use `renderItem={({item, index})}` and everything is typed correctly. The construct `({ item: Suggestion, index: number})` does not exist.

Comment: The FlatList does not have a onPress prop....